# Ruby on Rails: Uploading to Amazon S3 (Not attach it to any models)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am wondering is it possible to upload images to AMAZON S3 via paperclip without making it as attachment to any models.
I simply want to upload it and get the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use paperclip, you'll need to create a class with some of the ActiveRecord modules included, such as validations and callbacks to fulfill Paperclip requirements.

However, this is not attached to the database in any form, and it is a good and decoupled way to use Paperclip's facilities.

Here is a gist that can help you on that task:

https://gist.github.com/basgys/5712426

I hope that helps =P